# Permnent 301 redirect from CloudFlare

Tags: redirect, cloudflare, http-status-code-301

We are running Google Ad, and for one of the campaign, we have a URL of the format
`https://xxx.co/utm?&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_subsource=Search&utm_campaign=LS_Brand_March_23&utm_adgroup=Brand_Exact&utm_device=c&utm_placement=&gclid=CjwKCAjwwb6lBhBJEiwAbuVUSjGvp-ZnYe_k73B2MXhH8Kd7ZU8qzOfiOL7tfAH--2qjotd7DZ6MGBoCXogQAvD_BwE`

However, when a user clicks it, we get a 301 permanent redirect to the homepage https://xxx.co.
We have double-checked all our transform rules in Cloudflare plus our Google ad settings and cannot determine what could be causing this.

As a further test, we create another ad with the same URL format but a different campaign name, and that ad doesn't redirect; it takes the user to the intended destination. The problem of 301 redirects is with the above URL only, which negatively impacts our campaign.

Any clue or hint would help